# Iterating through items and assign each item the material-ui grow component

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

As the title says,

I am trying to iterate through an array of items and for each item, have the material-ui Grow component applied,
I cannot figure out the transitionDelay for this however.

Desired outcome is to have each item rendered a few ms after the previous item.

Unfortunately the transitionDelay is never called.

Can anyone help?

```
{ isMounted && items.map((item, i) => (
                <Grow  in style = {{transformOrigin: '0 0 0'}} 
                {...{transitionDelay: `${i + 1}00ms`}}
                  {...{timeout: 1300}}>
                    { item }
                </Grow>
            ))}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`transitionDelay` is not a a valid prop for [Grow](https://material-ui.com/api/grow/#grow-api) but it's a css property you can add to style:

```
{ isMounted && items.map((item, i) => (
                <Grow in style = {{
                    transformOrigin: '0 0 0',
                    transitionDelay: `${i + 1}00ms`
                  }}
                  {...{timeout: 1300}}>
                    { item }
                </Grow>
            ))}
```

[image: delay-material-ui]